# Is it possible to rename _id field after mongo's group aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, rename

I have a query like this (simplified):

```javascript
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { main_id: ObjectId("58f0f67f50c6af16709fd2c7") } }, 
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
      sum: { $sum: { $add: ["$P31", "$P32"] } }
    }
  }
])
```

I do this query from Java, and I want to map it on my class, but I don't want `_id` to be mapped on `name` field. Because if I do something like this:

```java
@JsonProperty("_id")
private String name;
```

then when I save this data back to mongo (after some modification) the data is saved with name as `_id` while I want a real Id to be generated.

So, how can I **rename** `_id` after `$group` operation?

Comment: [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) it on the next stage in the pipeline

Comment: {  $addFields: { newName: "$_id" } },
{ $project: { _id: 1 } }

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage at the end of your pipeline like this :

```
{ $project: {  
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      count: 1,
      sum: 1
   }
}
```

try it online: [mongoplayground.net/p/QpVyh-0I-bP](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QpVyh-0I-bP)

Answer (score 38):

From mongo v3.4 you could use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in conjunction with `$project` to avoid to write all the fields in `$project` that could be **very tedious**.

This happen in `$project` because if you include specifically a field, the other fields will be automatically excluded.

Example:

```
{ 
  $addFields: { my_new_id_name: "$_id" }
},
{
  $project: { _id: 0 }
}
```

Comment: Did not work for me, I get `$projection requires at least one output field.` (using it in an aggregate)

Comment: Clarification: I'm using DocumentDB in AWS

Comment: It works fine, but I need to convert _id to string, so `{ $addFields: { id: {  $toString: '$_id' } } }` and the order of the pipeline should be respected, first `$addFields` and `$project`.

Answer (score 5):

```
 db.report.aggregate(   
{     
$group: {_id: '$name'} 
},
{
$project:{
  name:"$_id",
 _id:false} }
 )
```

Answer (score 4):

Starting in `Mongo 4.2`, you can use a combination of [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) / [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) stages:

```javascript
// { x: 1, z: "a" }
// { x: 2, z: "b" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { y: "$x" } },
  { $unset: "x" }
])
// { y: 1, z: "a" }
// { y: 2, z: "b" }
```

The [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/) stage adds the new field to documents and the [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/) stage removes/excludes the field to be renamed from documents.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `find` method you can't do this, but if you using `aggregation` it is very easy like this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            newName: "$existingKeyName"
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example In Java using MongoTemplate:

```
GroupOperation groupByMovie = Aggregation.group("movieId")
                .avg("rating").as("averageRating");

        SortOperation sortByAvgRatingDesc = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "averageRating");
        LimitOperation limitRows = Aggregation.limit(limit);
        ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project()
                .and("_id").as("movieId")
                .and("averageRating").as("averageRating")
                .andExclude("_id");

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                groupByMovie,
                projectionOperation,
                sortByAvgRatingDesc,
                limitRows
        );

        AggregationResults<TopRatedMovie> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, MovieRating.class, TopRatedMovie.class);

        return results.getMappedResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

As all of the answers are written the solution in MongoDB query despite the question seeks the solution in Java, posting my approach using Java for posterities.

After the grouping, we can rename the `_id` fieldname using
`Projections.computed("<expected field name>", "$_id")))`

To Transform the core part of the query mentioned in the question to Java

```
        Bson mainIdMatch = match(eq("main_id", new ObjectId("58f0f67f50c6af16709fd2c7")));
        Bson group = Aggregates.group("$name", Accumulators.sum("count", 1L));
        Bson project = Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.excludeId(),
                Projections.computed("name", "$_id")));
        reportMongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(mainIdMatch, group, project))
                .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

To answer specifically, I have added an excerpt from the above code snippet, where I am renaming `_id` field value as name using `Projections.computed("name", "$_id")` which map the values of `_id` which we got as a result of grouping to the field called `name`. Also, we should exclude the id using `Projections.excludeId()`.

```
Aggregates.project(Projections.fields(Projections.excludeId(),
                Projections.computed("name", "$_id")))
```