# Alias for each "_id" in array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

How can i set alias for each "_id" in array of students.
I want to set an alias for _id in this json output.

```
{
    "items": [
        { 
            "id": "5d7aa7c1cba3435ebcb069c6",
            "start": "2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2019-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
            "description": "test",
            "students": [
                {
                    "_id": "5d7aa779cba3435ebcb069c5", // <- alias _id to id
                    "name": "Jon",
                    "surname": "Snow"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i do that with Aggregation operations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoose (mongodb) Alias \_id field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363513/mongoose-mongodb-alias-id-field)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537943/is-it-possible-to-rename-id-field-after-mongos-group-aggregation/52913757#52913757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator in your aggregate pipeline to transform the array. You would need to nest two [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operations; one 
for the `items` array and an inner [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) for the `students` array:

```
const studentsMap = {
    '$map': {
        'input': '$$this.students',
        'as': 'student',
        'in': {
            'id': '$$student._id',
            'name': '$$student.name',
            'surname': '$$student.surname'
        }
    }
}

db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$addFields': {
        'items': {
            '$map': {
                'input': '$items',
                'in': {
                    'id': '$$this.id',
                    'start': '$$this.start',
                    'end': '$$this.end',
                    'description': '$$this.description',
                    'students': studentsMap
                }
            }
        }
    } }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map to transform.

```
items = items.map((item)=>{
  item.students = item.students.map((student)=>{
    student.id = student._id;
    delete student._id;
    return student;
  })
  return item;
})
```

Comment: It worked! Is there any way to do this using the $project operator of agregation?

Comment: sorry mate, can not help you in that.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to **avoid hard coding of the fields in the $map stage** as the maintenance of such queries becomes difficult when document size grows. The following query can get us the expected output and it's independent of the fields present in the document. As it would only focus on replacing the `_id` present in `items.students`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "items":{
                $map:{
                    "input":"$items",
                    "as":"item",
                    "in":{
                        $mergeObjects:[
                            "$$item",
                            {
                                "students":{
                                    $map:{
                                        "input":"$$item.students",
                                        "as":"student",
                                        "in":{
                                            $mergeObjects:[
                                                "$$student",
                                                {
                                                    "id":"$$student._id"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "items.students._id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```