# Need a Mongo query to generate a particular result-set with aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am new to mongodb, I have a requirement and would like to know how to generate custom resultset using Mongo aggregate operator. Any help would be appreciated.

Need to group the collection by "**company**" and "**status**" and would need to produce resultset given below.

**Collection**

```
[
  {
    "company": "google",
    "status": "active",
    "offer": {
      "job": "developer",
      "salary": 10000.00
    },
    
  },
  {
    "company": "google",
    "status": "active",
    "offer": {
      "job": "designer",
      "salary": 500000.00
    },
    
  },
  {
    "company": "amazon",
    "status": "inactive",
    "offer": {
      "job": "designer",
      "salary": 500000.00
    },
    
  }
]
```

**Expected Result-Set**

```
[
  {
      "company" : "google",
      "report" : [{
          "status" : "active",
          "totalSalary" : 60000
      },
      {
          "status" : "inactive",
          "totalSalary" : 0
      }]
  },
  {
      "company" : "amazon",
      "report" : [{
          "status" : "active",
          "totalSalary" : 0
      },
      {
          "status" : "inactive",
          "totalSalary" : 500000.00
      }]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should 100% check the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) on aggregates, it's a bit complicated at first but once you get the hang of it they're great. I also recommend you https://mongoplayground.net/, it's a great site for doing this kind of tests.

What you're looking for is something like this

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        company: "$company"
      },
      report: {
        $addToSet: "$offer"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D_ciZS_b3Ee). You also probably want to rename the resulting _id field that's mandatory in a group aggregate. You can find how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537943/is-it-possible-to-rename-id-field-after-mongos-group-aggregation/48683015)

Comment: Thanks Webox, for the quick response. I need multiple fields (company & status) and result should group it based on the field "company"

Comment: My bad, you're looking to add up all active and inactive in one single element of the report array. So every report will have one "active" adding up all active jobs and 1 inactive  (per company) adding up all inactive reports? And if there are 0 of one category it should be 0?

Comment: Absolutely, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: I can generate something similar; however, I need to dedup the company by taking it out .[
  {
    "company": "google",
    "status": "active",
    "total": 10000
  },
  {
    "company": "google",
    "status": "inactive",
    "total": 500000
  },
  {
    "company": "amazon",
    "status": "inactive",
    "total": 500000
  }
]